# Why doesn't Meteor 1.6.1 use the latest version (1.5.2) of cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp?

Tags: android, nginx, meteor, cordova-plugins, okhttp

### First, the larger context:

We're working our way through an issue with Nginx on the server side, and the Okhttp library in our Meteor Cordova Android app.

Issue is discussed here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2543

**Problem summary:** Hot code push is broken in the Android app due to the manifest download failing, thanks to the above Nginx / Okhttp hijinks. (We *could* solve with an Nginx tweak/update but trying to avoid due to other reasons.)

### My actual question:

Looking at the newly-released Meteor 1.6.1 (), it looks like it's still specifying a dependency on `cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp` version 1.4.2. See [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/38792f5117e39f53d371a7f0af499120f5f603fc/packages/webapp/package.js#L25).

```
Cordova.depends({
  ...
  'cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp': '1.4.2'
});
```

1.4.2 uses Okhttp version 3.1.2, which is problematic for us.

There is, however, a `cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp` version 1.5.2 which uses Okhttp 3.9.1. See [here](https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/blob/master/plugin.xml#L114).

This newer Okhttp version solves our problem, but with Meteor 1.6.1 still specifying `cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp` 1.4.2, I can't use it.

- Why is the latest release version of Meteor using the older cordova plugin version?
- Is there a way to force it to the newer version (don't think so)?
- Are there plans to use the updated version?

Comment: also interested in this, but definitely deserve to open an issue.

Comment: note that the 1.6.2 should point to a new version https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.6.2/packages/webapp/package.js#L25